# How to stop VBA PowerPoint script from turning entire text box bold.

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a VBA script that finds a word and replaces it, within a PowerPoint slide. It searches each text box on the slide for the words. One text box does not have the words in it, but has some text in bold. For reason when I run the script, it turns all text in that box bold.

Is there a line of code that I can input that can avoid this?

```
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Text1", ", NewText")
        End If
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Text2", "New Text, 2017")
        End If
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Text3", "New Text")
        End If
End If
Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: You're replacing text which doesn't need to be replaced  - you can first use Instr() to check if your search term is part of the text: if it isn't, then don't perform the Replace step.  The reason it's all turning bold is likely that the first character is bolded: if you replace the whole content it will pick up the formatting of the first character.  To replace without losing existing formatting, look into using the `Characters` collection.

Comment: In addition to Tim's suggestion, you can put all three replace statements within one If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then / End If test.